# How to create a DialogFragment layout with multiple pages or tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

In my application, I want to implement a dialog fragment in which the user configures 1 to 4 sets of data (for lack of a better phrase).  The number of "pages" to be set up is up to the user, so I would like the dialog fragment display to respond dynamically to the number requested by the user, by varying the number of viewable "screens".

My first thought was to implement a tabbed display with the tabs displayed or hidden as requested, but the way Android seems to think about tabs seems to be way more complicated than this.  (Like this over-the-top example: [How to create an Android Tabbed Dialog containing fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634519/how-to-create-an-android-tabbed-dialog-containing-fragments))

Is there a simple layout technique I'm missing that I could use for this?  Perhaps a nice example somewhere on the web??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try and use a ViewPager - http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It supports sliding pages in both directions. You can add custom animation to it - using buttons or whatever views to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: That certainly looks promising.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No problem. I hope you nail it.

Comment: It took a bit of editing from the original example -- using getChildFragmentManager(), for instance, instead of getSupportFragmentManager() -- but I've got a pager inside my dialog fragment...  And it's kinda pretty....   Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help